# NextJs failed to collect page data for /a

Tags: next.js13

Am in nextJS version 13.4. But when I run npm run build, its saying a build error occurred:

> Error : Failed to collect page data for /a at node_modules\next\dist\build\utils.js at processTicksAndRejections.

When I remove that page from the project, it does the same for the next page, like it then says failed to collect page data for /b, when I remove /b it will be like failed to collect page data for  /c and so on. Please help me fix. There is nothing complex in my pages. For eg in the /a page, its just a component returning a div tag written connect in it.

I tried to clear the cache. It didn't change anything.

---

The code is not even complex. Like for the page /a :

```
function Conn(){return (<div>Page a </>)} export default Conn
```

It's just the same for all pages. It's working fine when I run npm run dev , but throwing an error that failed to collect page data at /a.... when I run npm run build. Can this be caused by libraries?

Comment: May i see your code ?

Comment: The code is not even complex. Like for the page /a : function Conn(){return (<div>Page a </>)} export default Conn. It's just the same for all pages. It's working fine when I run npm run dev , but throwing an error that failed to collect page data at /a.... when I run npm run build. Can this be caused by libraries? Help please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.